# jQuery add $(this) to callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

How can I add `$(this)` to the following code in the callback?  I don't have access to `$(this)` in the callback function if i simply try adding it.

```
$('.example').myPlugin({
    option1: hello, 
    option2: world,
    callback: function () {
      // use $(this)
    }
 });
```

**Edit:** How can I add for example `var $this = $(this)` inside `$('.example').myPlugin({... })` before the callback?

Part of plugin with callback:

```
var base = this;

// Access to jQuery and DOM versions of element
base.$el = $(el);
base.el = el;

base.pluginName = function () {
...
// Callback
if (typeof base.options.callback === 'function') {
  base.options.callback.call(el);
}
...
}
```

Comment: You'll have to refactor your code to access it in the callback, there's no direct way to access the literal object from the code creating it. But a solution would be to improve the plugin so that it can accept data (as does jQuery's `on`) or a context as additional arguments.

Comment: Show us the code that calls the callback.

Comment: @Bergi the callback code is in a plugin which I can't modify

Comment: @CyberJunkie: Ah, `.myPlugin` did suggest otherwise. Better use "`somePlugin`" in your question…  What specific plugin is it and what does it? It might need some trickery.

Comment: @Bergi i just want to add a variable for example `var this = $(this)` into `$('.example').myPlugin({...})` regardless of the plugin. I'm just not sure where/how to place the variable.

Comment: @CyberJunkie: The proper way would be that the plugin does call the callback with the expected value of `this`. File a bug report if it doesn't. Or tell us about your exact situation and we'll find you a workaround.

Comment: @Bergi ok I see. Please see updated post. I added the plugin code that handles the callback.

Comment: Um, that code suggestst that just using `$(this)` in the callback should work (as `this` refers to the respective `el`). Please show us your code of the attempt to use this plugin. What do you need the `$(this)` for, where did you place it, and what did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the value of this to a variable when it is in scope and then use the variable instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your callback function will scope this to the global context (ie window). Do this to get a handle on it outside of your callback function.

```
var examples = $('.example');
for(var i = 0; i < examples.length; i++)
{
    var me = $(examples[i]);
    me.myPlugin({
        option1: hello, 
        option2: world,
        callback: function () {
          // use "me" here
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. The variable has to be in myPlugin.

Comment: You mean inside the callback function? It can't be.

Comment: within `$('.example').myPlugin({` before option1.. option2.. The idea is to have access to the `$('.example')` selector inside the callback.

Comment: OK, I've changed my post to reflect this.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that will target only the first element with class `.example`. The var still has to be set within `$('.example').myPlugin({... })` to be within the selector loop in case there are multiple selectors. (tested)